# How to create screenshot using Windows snipping tool with cut out border?

Tags: windows-10, screenshot, snipping

I see screenshots like the one below that have "uneven" (cut out like) borders. I was told they were created using the built-in snipping tool. I don't see that option inside the app on my Windows 10.

How do I accomplish this without additional edits please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the snip window, you'll see a drop-down arrow next to the New button.  Clicking this shows the different snip options available.  If you select 'Free-form snip' you can make the scissors cut according to how you move the mouse.  Snipping the windows from your image using the free-form option gave me this:

[image: jagged little snip]

I have to admit I don't know how to reproduce the shadow effect in your image.

Comment: Interesting - I knew about the free hand, but I found it hard to believe someone would spend the time to do so, I expect to do a rectangle and have the cut out + the shadow done automatically :-) Thanks for the idea. Let's see if someone can come up with another insight

Comment: It is a very ragged shape.  I wouldn't expect a lightweight tool of this nature to automagically provide (dynamic?) cutout shapes.  However, like you I also think it would take someone with too much time on their hands. Yup, watch this space.

Comment: Given this came from a very practical developer I would think no manual work was involved ;-)

Comment: You should ask the developer for a demo on how it was done.

Answer (score 2):

The tool SnagIt provides the features discussed here, with or without shadows, etc.  It is much easier than using the snipping tool/scissors method - you can find several demos online to help.

Answer (score -1):

Use above method snip scissors

Then for shadows

I think easy way would be copy that image Ctrl + C on snipping tool after scissors and paste it into MS word... click on image and go to "format tab" and then select shadow option. it will deal with shadow and there are also many other features

then from word you could able to share, copy or save "Shadowed image".

Comment: This answer is difficult to understand.  A partial answer is acceptable, but even partial answers need to be understandable *without* requiring one to read other posts. Please [edit] your answer to improve its clarity.